# kint content redirects me to the installation page

Tags: drupal-8

I am using a Classy template to practice Drupal for the first time.
In one of the blocks I managed to use kint and could see the content in an array like this:

```
{{ kint(content) }}
```

Now, however, I created a new file(a duplicate of the original under the core themes) and named node--article--full.html.twig

In that file, I tried to use the same code

```
{{ kint(content) }}
```

I cleared all caches and visited the article; but when it loads, for some reason its taking me to the localhost/themename/core/install.php

The complete file looks like below:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
  ]
%}
{{ attach_library('classy/node') }}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if display_submitted %}
    <footer class="node__meta">
      {{ author_picture }}
      <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
        {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content') }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
  {{ kint(content) }}
Hi there from the full node template of the aticle content type
</article>
```

Anything wrong with this particular file perhaps?
Note that if I remove the kint content, the file works.

Answer (score 0):

As `kint` consumes a lot of resources, there are high chances that your database ran out of resources. A pretty common fix is to reduce the number of accessible levels via `kint`.

You can find more info [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243502/kint-leads-to-install-php).
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that if the code cannot see the database, it assumes that you must be installing Drupal.